# How do I auto refresh the displayed value using Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, twilio

I have a Ruby app running on Heroku with Sinatra and the Twilio API.

The queue works, and I can create an ERB that will display the number of calls in the queue. If a call is in the queue and I refresh it will show the new number.

How do I make it do this automatically, whether that means the browser auto refreshes, or the page itself pulls from the API every X seconds?

```
get '/display' do
account_sid = 'sid'
auth_token  = 'token'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

# Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
# check out the list resource examples on this page
queue = @client.account.queues.list.each do |queue|
friendlyName = queue.friendly_name

end

@size =     @client.account.queues.get("sid")
    @display = @size.current_size
    erb :display
end
```

display.erb has this:

```
Current queue size is <%= @display %>
```

So how can I make it refresh so that my users are shown an updated queue size periodically? Or do I just put that object into the ERB file and have it run on a loop?

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I make it refresh so that my users are shown an updated
>   queue size periodically?

One solution would be to use an ajax call back to the server.  You make the ajax call with javascript that you put in the html page.  With ajax, the page wouldn't have to be continually reloaded--instead the new information would be inserted into the page.  The ajax call an be initiated with javascript's `setInterval()` function to make it repeat over and over.

You could also use WebSockets to open a persistent connection and push the data from the server to the client.  That would require a timed loop on the server side that periodically pushes the data.

I recommend the ajax route.